# WP REST API V2 wp/v2/media problems

Tags: android, json, wordpress, rest

I am working on an android app for practice, that for now gets all the posts and their featured images and displays them in a listview.
The problem is, and this started happening a few posts ago, I create a new post, set a featured image and publish it.
It appears in wp/v2/posts, but the featured image doesn't appear in wp/v2/media.
Under _links/wp:featuredmedia there is a link to the image in wp/v2/media, but when I press it, it says rest_forbidden.
And now my app can't access the featured images of the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your featured image must be related to a published post (or you'll need to tweak the media post_status in the database).
More informations about this here : https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2596